# Wordpress: how to create a plugin/template page with a form (an manage the form submissions)

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I need to create a couple of pages to subscribe and unsubscribe users to a newsletter service (I can't use any available plugin, its a custom newsletter service) so I need to create a page where to show the forms and manage the form submissions.

I'm not a wordpress expert so I don't know exactly how to i.e. make a page that reponds to /newsletter/subscribe|unsubscribe and display a form on it.
I've done some plugins in the past but none of them render a page responding to an URL or "capture" the POST.

I've done some investigations and it looks like adding this to the functions file of my template I can add rewrite rules:

```
function custom_rewrite_newsletters() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^newsletter/subscribe/?', 'index.php?pagename=subscribe', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^newsletter/unsubscribe/?', 'index.php?pagename=unsubscribe', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_newsletters');
```

The problems is I don't know where to create the subscribe and unsubscribe pages. I tried page-subscribe.php in the root of my theme but I get a 404

Thanks in advance

Comment: Gravity forms can handle GET and POST requests http://www.gravityforms.com/

Comment: not exactly what I'm looking for, I want to create a page where I can use the newsletter api to susbcribe or unsubscribe a user